# No base DN returned from server.Plase enter the base DN manually- Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ldap, apache-ds

I'm new in Ldap and trying to setup it manually on centos and i'm getting below error while access it from  Apache Directory studio.

No base DN returned from server.Plase enter the base DN manually- Apache Directory Studio  .

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the LDAP server didn't provide it's base DN name to the client and you have to configure it yourself.

The base DN (distinguished name) is the base name of the directory tree (e.g. `cn=example,cn=com`) and you should have configured it when setting up the LDAP server.

Comment: I have already provided that..that is the reason i'm able to get authneticated but not able  fetch base DN in ADS.